# problem in creating a trigger

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers, mysql-error-1064

I am facing a problem in creating a trigger and i am not sure why this is erroring out.can you please help me.

I have written a trigger mentioned below and it gives me this error upon trying to execute the trigger ...

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DECLARE store_itemid INTEGER; store_hostid INTEGER; store_desc VARCHAR(255);' at line 4

#### Code:

```
mysql> delimiter //
   CREATE TRIGGER init_trigger 
   AFTER INSERT ON test_trigger
   FOR EACH ROW
   DECLARE 
     store_itemid INT;
     store_hostid INT;
     store_desc VARCHAR(255);
     store_key VARCHAR(255);
     store_lastvalue VARCHAR(255);
     store_lastclock VARCHAR(255);
     store_preval INT;
     store_status INT;
   BEGIN

     SELECT itemid into store_itemid,
            hostid into store_hostid,
            description into store_desc,
            key_ into store_key,
            lastvalue into store_lastvalue,
            lastclock into store_lastclock,
            prevvalue into store_preval,
            status into store_status 
       FROM test_triggers 
      WHERE lastvalue > 80;

     IF store_lastvalue > 80 THEN
        INSERT INTO test_triggers1 
          (itemid,hostid,description,key,lastvalue,lastclock,prevvalue,status) 
        VALUES
          (store_itemid,store_hostid,store_desc,store_key,store_lastvalue,store_lastclock,store_preval,store_status);

     END IF;
   END;
   //
```

Comment: you should post you question here, rather tyhan link elsewhere

Answer (score 0):

U must add "BEGIN" after "ROW"